# Adding associated tasks to a meeting

Tags: web-part, calendar, tasks

I've got a meeting booking system that automatically adds meetings to a calendar. I need end-users to be able to view this meeting and be able to add a task into a task list, and view that particular meeting's tasks in the calendar entry.

My problem is I'm not sure how to relate the task with the meeting? I currently have it set to show all tasks in the task list as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a lookup column to tie items from the separate lists together.  How you setup the viewing connection in the Tasks list and Calendar list varies.

**On the Tasks list side**
These steps will create a link in the task item’s form to the Meeting item.  When you view the Task’s display form it will provide a link in the lookup

column to the calendar entry.

1. In your Tasks list, create a lookup column to the Calendar list.

**On the Calendar list side**
These steps will show the related tasks in the event display form.  Your lookup column in the Tasks list must be created prior to these steps.

1. On the Calendar list’s ribbon, on the Calendar tab, in the Customize List group, click Form Web Parts.  Select Default Display Form.
2. Click Add a Web Part.
3. Select the Tasks list.
4. Move the Tasks list web part under the event display form web part.
5. On the events display web part click the drop down arrow on the far right side and select Connections, and then Provide Row of Data To.
6. On the Configure Connection tab, in the Connection Type drop down, select Get Filter Values From.
7. Hit Configure.
8. Select the event field name you perform the lookup on, and the related task column.
9. Click Ok.